# XtraBars.PopupMenu: How access Items inside PopupMenuItemLinkCollection

Tags: devexpress

Product version 9.1.2.

I am writing an event handler for the BeforePopup event for an Xtrabars.PopupMenu. I would like to disable certain items and was following this approach I found on the DevExpress support forum.

```
private void popupMenu1_BeforePopup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { 
       (sender as      DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu).ItemLinks[1].Item.Enabled = ! (sender as DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu).ItemLinks[1].Item.Enabled; 
}
```

In the event handler I get the XtraBars.PopupMenu sender object and then access the links via the ItemLinks property as shown above. ItemLinks returns an object of type PopupMenuItemLinkCollection. But this object is unindexable. I can find no documentation on PopupMenuItemLinkCollection.

How can I access the items in the PopupMenuItemLinkCollection?

Comment: Did you try to contact Devexpress support to resolve this issue? AFAIK, it's free, even if you don't pay for subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the indexing via client side code.
1) Assign menu with some id (ex : `ID="menu"`)
2) Make a client side code as
 `<ClientSideEvents ItemClick="OnMenuItemClick" />`
3)

```
function OnMenuItemClick(){
var item = menu.GetSelectedItem();
}
```

item will provide you the index of current menu selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the method 'get_Item' that allows me to access the items in the collection:

links.get_Item(0)